# Guides/Tutorials on unobtrusive javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, unobtrusive-javascript

Google hasn't yielded satisfactory results. I'd appreciate it if people can provide some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by unobtrusive javascript/ajax? can you elaborate?

Comment: When you separate the javascript from the HTML markup. That means no more <... onclick=do_something()..>

Comment: @SoftwareGeek - What Tunji said pretty much.  While its usually described with more flowery language it pretty much boils down to using javascript in the header to attach scripts to dom events instead of the traditional method of making function calls from html elements in the body (from an onclick for example)

Comment: @kekekela - Ah, got it. jQuery is the way to go then.

Answer (score 2):

Decent but basic:
http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/johnteague/archive/2008/11/03/unobtrusive-javascript-part-2-separating-content-style-and-behavior.aspx

More in-depth but MVC specific:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/simonince/jquery-mvc-progressive-enhancement)

Answer (score 1):

The term "unobtrusive javascript" appears in one book named "jQuery in Action", I am not sure if that where it originates from, but it is worth reading for sure.

For my personal understanding, modern Javascript libraries/frameworks such like jQuery move the trend twoard this sort of "unobtrusive javascript". So I would say it might be something you'd like to invest on.